# Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this line:

```
$stmt->bind_result('d', $keyarray['payment_gross']);
```

and I get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference in /home/star1231/public_html/pdt.php on line 35

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not much I can tell about your code, but if parameter 1 is passed by reference in function definition then you need to do this.

```
$char = 'd';
$stmt->bind_result($char, $keyarray['payment_gross']);
```

Only variables can be passed by reference since you are passing the address of the variable and not an actual value. 
Let me know if it solves it

Comment: thanks for the answer, the real problem was that i confused with the function name :P , i suupose to use bind_param, but tanks anyway...

Answer (score 2):

You should use parameter type ONLY when you bind_param

```
$stmt->bind_param('d',$some_double_var);
```

but

```
$stmt->bind_result($answer_variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to this. First of all: What is 'd'?

The php interpreter cannot pass 'd' by reference, because it's a literal, not a variable.

That first parameter must be a variable (or list) name, or the same $stmt for the function overload.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Today got same issue with MongoDB

> Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference

```
// Failed
$TrialSend->insert(['d' => 'somevarible', 'w' => 1], array("w" => 1));
```

---

```
// No error fixed
$save = ['d' => 'somevarible', 'w' => 1];
$TrialSend->insert($save, array("w" => 1));
```