# Can I use class entities in bind_result

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

As I read in many post here I should use prepared statements whenever possible so this idea crossed my mind.

In the constructor of a class I use a prepared statement to get the data for the class entities.
I tried and get this error message:
Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference in ...

This is the code I used:

```
<?php
final class Getraenkeabo{
    private $id = 0;
    private $mitgliedsnr = 0;
    private $preis = 0.0;
    private $abbuchungstag = null;
    private $abbuchung_ab = null;
    private $abbuchung_bis = null;

    public function __get($key){
        if(!property_exists($this, $key)){
            throw new Exception('Zugriff auf nicht existente Eigenschaft '.$key);
        }
        else{
            return $this->$key;
        }
    }
    
    public function __set($key,$value){
        if(!property_exists($this, $key)){
            throw new Exception('Zugriff auf nicht existente Eigenschaft '.$key);
        }
        elseif($key == 'preis'){
            $this->preis == floatval($value);
        }
        elseif($key == 'abbuchungstag'){
            if(!is_null($value)){
                if($value == 1 || $value == 15){
                    $this->abbuchungstag = intval($value);
                }
                else{
                    throw new Exception('Als Abbuchungstag sind nur 1 oder 15 erlaubt. '.$value.' gegeben');
                }
            }
            else{
                $this->abbuchungstag = null;
            }
        }
        elseif($key == 'abbuchung_ab' || $key == 'abbuchung_bis'){
            if(!is_null($value)){
                if(is_null($this->abbuchungstag)){
                    throw new Exception('Um einen Abbuchungszeitraum zu bestimmen, muss zuerst der Abbuchungstag gesetzt werden.');
                }
                else{
                    if($key == 'abbuchung_bis' && strtotime($value) < strtotime($this->abbuchung_ab)){
                        throw new Exception('Das Abbuchungsende '.$value.' liegt nicht nach dem Abbuchungsanfang.');
                    }
                    else{
                        if(strtotime($value) !== false){
                            $this->key = $value;
                        }
                        else{
                            throw new Exception('Ungültiges Datum "'.$value.'" für '.__CLASS.__.'->'.$key);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                $this->$key = null;
            }
        }
        else{
            $this->$key = intval($value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Konstruktor
     * @param int $mitgliedsnr Mitgliedsnummer
     */
    function __construct($mitgliedsnr = 0){
        if($mitgliedsnr > 0){
            $this->mitgliedsnr = $mitgliedsnr;
            $stmt = $GLOBALS['db']->prepare('SELECT `id`,`mitgliedsnr`,`preis`,`abbuchungstag`,`abbuchung_ab`, `abbuchung_bis` FROM `getraenkeabo` WHERE `mitgliedsnr`=?');
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $mitgliedsnr);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result('iifiss', $this->id,$this->mitgliedsnr,$this->preis,$this->abbuchungstag,$this->abbuchung_ab,$this->abbuchung_bis);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
    function save(){
        $sql = sprintf(
            'REPLACE INTO `getraenkeabo` (`id`,`mitgliedsnr`,`preis`,`abbuchungstag`,`abbuchung_ab`, `abbuchung_bis`) VALUES (%d,%d,%s,%s,%s)',
            $this->id, $this->mitgliedsnr, $this->preis, (is_null($this->abbuchungstag))?'NULL':'"'.$this->abbuchungstag.'"',
            (is_null($this->abbuchung_ab))?'NULL':'"'.$this->abbuchung_ab.'"', (is_null($this->abbuchung_bis))?'NULL':'"'.$this->abbuchung_bis.'"'
        );
        $GLOBALS['db']->query($sql) OR die(writeErrorLogfile($GLOBALS['db']->error.$sql));
        if($this->id == 0){
            $this->id = $GLOBALS['db']->insert_id;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function delete(){
        require_once(__DIR__.'/class.Mitgliedschaft.php');
        $ms = new Mitgliedschaft($this->mitgliedsnr);
        if($ms->art instanceof Mitgliedschaftsart){
            $ms->art = new Mitgliedschaftsart($ms->art->vip_von);
            $ms->save();
        }
        $sql = sprintf('DELETE FROM `getraenkeabo` WHERE `id` = %d', $this->id);
        $GLOBALS['db']->query($sql) OR die(writeErrorLogfile($GLOBALS['db']->error.$sql));
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

I suspect the problem is because bind_param uses references instead of variables and may not be able to handle the dereference operator ->.
Is that so?

Comment: Are you sure the error does not lie in `bind_result` where you pass a string value as first param which might be the reason it cannot be used by reference?

Comment: Yeah, @Remy you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Ashes on my head. Turns out the problem was the same as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717113/fatal-error-cannot-pass-parameter-1-by-reference).

In bind_result you only have to specify the variables in which the columns of the dataset should be stored, not their data type. This is only necessary for bind_param. Seems to be a typical beginner's mistake. So because I a newbie to prepared statements don't be mad at me.
Thank you all for the quick help.